# How to use Scala case class from another Object

Tags: scala, class, object, traits, case-class

I have a trait:

```
Trait paramsNeeded {
    case class ThingOne (name: String, content: String)
    val pairs : Map [String, ThingOne] 
}
```

and class A extends this trait:

```
class aClass (id: String) extends paramsNeeded{
    val pairs : Map [String, ThingOne] = Map("aKey"->ThingOne("aName","aContent", id))
}
```

class B use aClass:

```
class bClass {
    val withID = new aClass("100") //pass in id 100
    val toBeUsedinC = withID.paris("aKey") //the intent is to return case class ThingOne, and use it in cObject 
}
```

Now in another object cObject I hope to use is `toBeUsedinC`, and have a function that takes it as a parameter. But it does not recognise the type case class ThingOne:

```
object cObject {
    def useParam (thingToUse:ThingOne) // it does not resolve symbol ThingOne 
}
```

So how can I use the `toBeUsedinC` in cObject and access it's value? Many thanks. Please let me know if the explanation is not clear. I am quite new to it.

Comment: `ThingOne` is a path-dependent class. Meaning there is a different class for each instance of `paramsNeeded` which is not probably what you want. I would just define the case class outside.

Comment: Thanks. I dont quite get it. You mean define the case class outside of the trait? I hope all the classes extend the trait use/have that case class `ThingOne` in `val paris`

Comment: Yeah all classes extending the trait can use the class regardless if it is defined inside or outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning up some of your earlier typos this compiles and runs.

```
object CObject {
  def useParam(thingToUse : AClass#ThingOne) = {}
}

val b = new BClass
CObject.useParam(b.toBeUsedinC)
```

Comment: thanks. but where did you create val b, like in which class? I hope to pass in id "100" in class B

Comment: Value `b` is created exactly where you see it. Outside of any other class or object. The class is defined exactly as you posted it (except I renamed it `BClass`).

Comment: but in a project, we need to put it in some file somewhere right..?

Comment: Code is compiled after being read from a file (or many files) except for the REPL which compiles code under _slightly_ different rules.

Comment: sorry I think I didn't ask it clearly, so if I write these in IDE but not a REPL, with these classes and objects in separate scala files, where should I put val b = new BClass?

Comment: You can put these classes and objects in separate files, or put everything in one file. Scala doesn't care. You can use helpful file names or goofy meaningless file names. Scala doesn't care. It's all just code to be compiled. You should create an instance of `BClass` wherever you need an instance of `BClass`. At the beginning of your program, at the end, wherever. Scala doesn't care. It's all just code to be compiled.